# reorder dictionary inside of nested dictionary based on key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the below list of dictionary:

```
test = [{'Date': datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 26, 0, 0),'Visitors': [{u'Owner_Name': u'Ashish Bainade', u'Unit_ID': u'1000', u'ID': u'Ashish ainade 119', u'In_Time': datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 26, 12, 13), u'Wing': u'Z'},{u'Owner_Name': u'Ashish Bainade', u'Unit_ID': u'102', u'ID': u'6976', u'In_Time': datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 26, 13, 15), u'Wing': u'B'}]}]
```

I want to order the sub-dictionary `Visitors` by key `In_Time` in descending order like below

```
test = [{'Date': datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 26, 0, 0),'Visitors': [{u'Owner_Name': u'Ashish Bainade', u'Unit_ID': u'102', u'ID': u'6976', u'In_Time': datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 26, 13, 15), u'Wing': u'B'},{u'Owner_Name': u'Ashish Bainade', u'Unit_ID': u'1000', u'ID': u'Ashish ainade 119', u'In_Time': datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 26, 12, 13), u'Wing': u'Z'}]}]
```

I am trying to go down this approach :
`from operator import itemgetter`

But I am Unable to get the desired output , is there any way or suggestion that can help me ?

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: I wanted in nested dictionary not normal dictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just sort the sub-dictionary `Visitors` and assign it back.

```
test[0]['Visitors'] = sorted(test[0]['Visitors'], key = lambda x: x['In_Time'], reverse = True)
```

If you want to use `itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
test[0]['Visitors'] = sorted(test[0]['Visitors'], key=itemgetter('In_Time'), reverse=True)
```

Input:

```
[{'Date': datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 26, 0, 0),
  'Visitors': [{u'ID': u'Ashish ainade 119',
    u'In_Time': datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 26, 12, 13),
    u'Owner_Name': u'Ashish Bainade',
    u'Unit_ID': u'1000',
    u'Wing': u'Z'},
   {u'ID': u'6976',
    u'In_Time': datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 26, 13, 15),
    u'Owner_Name': u'Ashish Bainade',
    u'Unit_ID': u'102',
    u'Wing': u'B'}]}]
```

Output:

```
[{'Date': datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 26, 0, 0),
  'Visitors': [{u'ID': u'6976',
    u'In_Time': datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 26, 13, 15),
    u'Owner_Name': u'Ashish Bainade',
    u'Unit_ID': u'102',
    u'Wing': u'B'},
   {u'ID': u'Ashish ainade 119',
    u'In_Time': datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 26, 12, 13),
    u'Owner_Name': u'Ashish Bainade',
    u'Unit_ID': u'1000',
    u'Wing': u'Z'}]}]
```